# Find out AVG column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this php/sql Query:

```
$result = mysql_query("
            SELECT r.item_id, AVG(rating) AS avgrating, count(rating) AS count, i.item, c.category
            FROM ratings AS r
            LEFT JOIN items AS i
            ON r.item_id = i.items_id
            INNER JOIN master_cat c
            ON c.cat_id = i.cat_id
            GROUP BY item_id 
            ORDER BY avgrating DESC 
            LIMIT 25;");
```

When I output this, count is correct, it shows how much votes certain items have received.

I simply want to add a `WHERE count >= 10` clause but everything breaks.  Obviously, when there are thousands of items, some will get one vote and have 100%.  But that is not a good indicator.  I want to print out items that have at least 10 votes (or `count >= 10`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use `having` instead `where`

```
SELECT 
    r.item_id, AVG(rating) AS avgrating, 
    count(rating) AS count, i.item, c.category
FROM 
    ratings AS r
    LEFT JOIN items AS i
        ON r.item_id = i.items_id
    INNER JOIN master_cat c
        ON c.cat_id = i.cat_id
GROUP BY 
    item_id 
HAVING
    count >= 10
ORDER BY 
    avgrating DESC 
LIMIT 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell it what you want to count

```
having count(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `where` filter on the results of an aggregate function (`count()`). `where` is applied at the row-level, as the DB is deciding whether to include the row or not in the result set - at this point the results of the count aren't available yet.

What you want is a `having` clause, which is applied as one of the last steps before results are sent to the client, after all the aggregate results have been calculated.

```
...
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING count > 10
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: @tombom: mysql allows use of aliases in where/having. Rolling back the edit.